# 404 - File or directory not found in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am developing a MVC web application. Testing locally

http://localhost:28847/Place/Malaysia works perfectly how ever, When I deploy this web application in hosting server

http://videeows.com/Place/Malaysia  **I get 404 - File or directory not found.**

The app is deployed in asp.net version 4.5 in the server.
What could have possibly gone wrong?

There are other MVC sites deployed in the machine which works perfectly.
my MVC is just a redirection.

http://videeows.com/Place/Malaysia this will redirect to http://videeows.com/Place.aspx?s=Malaysia&q=Coun

http://videeows.com will direct to http://videeows.com/default.aspx

my routeconfig is:

```
  public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Place",
    url: "Place/",
    defaults: new { controller = "Place", action = "Index" }
    );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "PlaceByCountry",
            url: "Place/{country}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Country", action = "IndexByCountry", country = "" }
            );

        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Default",
           url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional });
    }
```

Comment: Do it just fail with this one page or is the entire site down?

Comment: Likely it's the IIS configuration for this site. You can find some good tips [here](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/Mar/27/ASPNET-Routing-not-working-on-IIS-70)

Comment: Another site in the same server works while this doesnot. I have checked the application pool and website settings. Its set to 4.0

Comment: I have the same problem;  Didn't find any solution ?

Comment: @Venkat : Were you able to find a solution for the problem you have mentioned above? Your reply would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is unlikely to be a problem with ASP .NET MVC code.  It must be to do with the way you have set-up the server.  It's difficult to say what it is though.  Make sure that your app pool supports the .NET version which you are using etc.

Answer (score 0):

Check your IIS Server settings and App pool you are using. Just fire and check http://localhost:8080/ IIS working
Make sure that your app pool supports the .NET version which you are using.

Comment: all done. it is still not working. App pool points to clr version 4.0

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem : for certain pages, I get a 404 Error message. In fact is that the server does not consider the last part of the URL as an "id", but instead a folder name. And indeed this folder doesn't exist. I think it can happens when a link is just a call to RedirectToAction to another function...

A solution can be, Instead of using :

```
AreaName/ControllerName/FunctionName/IdReference
```

use

```
AreaName/ControllerName/FunctionName?Id=IdReference
```